# How to write a class in Micropython that can be initialized with arguments?

Tags: python, micropython

I'm trying to write a class in Micropython that needs to be initialized with an argument, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

I'm using an XBee module with micropython 1.9.4

This is how I'm declaring the class:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, myArgument):
        self.classVar = myArgument
```

But when I try to initialize my class like this:

```
c = myClass(argumentValue)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to declare `classVar` before I make reference to it?

### Edit (Solved)

I was able to find the error, I noticed that I was defining another `__init__` method elsewhere in the code that didn't received any arguments.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've updated the question with full trace.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Can you please now update the full code ? :)

Comment: @Exho Thank you for the tip. It turns out I had already defined another ´__init__´ method elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [documentation about Python Object Creation](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/reference/isr_rules.html#creation-of-python-objects) ?

> ISR’s cannot create instances of Python objects. This is because MicroPython needs to allocate memory for the object from a store of free memory block called the heap.

Comment: Can you give more information instead of just a link?

Comment: Well the code sample isn't complete so it's kinda hard to find out what's wrong. It can be a lot of things, so I didn't wanted to adventure myself on a wrong path, the specific documentation about the project should be necessary to solve the problem. But I'll give it a try by quoting the documentation

Comment: That's only relevant to interrupt handlers (ISR's). If the original poster's code is not in an interrupt handler it doesn't apply.